# MSP430 RTC_B Back up Battery Supply

Tags: oscillator, crystal, msp430, rtc

I plan on using MSP430F5636IPZ from Texas Instruments as my microcontroller in a project which I am currently working on. The MCU comes with a RTC_B (Real Time Clock) with Battery Backup capability.
According to this article : "" https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa665b/slaa665b.pdf "" which I found for hardware implementation considers the usage of MSPTS430PZ100USB target board and  MSP-EXP430F5529LP LaunchPad kit interface, which I believe is a beginners kit which I don't need since MSP430F5636IPZ is a single chip MCU which I am trying to design on a PCB board.

Can somebody help me to understand the hardware design listed in the article and how I  can implement it in my design?

From reading the datasheet, I figured out that pin 87(Vbat) and pin 88(Vbak) are used to implement the battery backup along with RTC_B module (including a 32.768 KHz crystal oscillator).

Please Help!!

Comment: Can you be more specific i.e. can you indicate which part of the pdf document you wish to reproduce? Maybe add a picture of a schematic and explain which parts you are having the most difficulty with. At the moment, your question is too broad to make a definitive answer. Maybe you need to find the demo board schematic too.

Answer (score 1):

You need a programmer/debugger. The MSP-EXP430F5529LP LaunchPad kit has a debugger built in, it is the top portion of the board. To use a different target, remove the row of jumpers and connect to your custom target. The USB connector at the top left connects to you PC. This is how I do it.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau533d/slau533d.pdf

[image]

Or, you can use a dedicated debugger such as the MSP-FET. This is more expensive, and I have never seen the advantage to this method.

Or, you can use the MSP-TS430PZ100USB with a socket for your MCU. If TI doesn't have a Launchpad development kit for your exact MCU, then this is what you use until you have a custom board.

Comment: The modern (black) MSP-FET has current sensor and a UART back channel for easier debugging.